# EEPROM stops responding after sequential read

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, xc8

I'm using a 24C256 eeprom with a PIC18F4550 microcontroller and the xc8 i2c library functions. I can make a random read of any given adress, but when I attempt to make a sequential read it only works between adresses 0x0000 and 0x0031.

If try to make a sequential read from 0x0032 to 0x003F the eeprom stops responding after I finish reading and the microcontroller hangs if it tries to make any other read operation. The code for the sequential reading function I'm using is the one below

```
StartI2C();
IdleI2C();
putcI2C(0b10100000);//write eeprom
__delay_us(20);
IdleI2C();
putcI2C(address_h);
__delay_us(20);
IdleI2C();
putcI2C(address_l);
IdleI2C();
__delay_us(20);
StartI2C();
IdleI2C();
putcI2C(0b10100001);//read eeprom
__delay_us(20);
IdleI2C();
while(bytes_to_read){ //it starts with the amount of bytes to read
    IdleI2C();
    *string_received_data++ = ReadI2C();

    if(--bytes_to_read)AckI2C();//only gives ack if there's more data to read
}
NotAckI2C();
StopI2C();
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure you're talking about hexadecimal addresses? 2) Implement a function that sends a single 0xFF byte and call that in-between EEPROM accesses to unblock the I2C bus 3) if 2) helped, your peripheral is pulling the SDA line low, likely a wiring/frequency/pull-up problem. 4) There is a RestartI2C() function, use it. 5) See if DataRdyI2C() helps. 6) Try actually writing to the memory first and reading back the data and see if there is a mismatch.

Comment: 1)Oh, sorry I meant decimal adresses. For now I found a temporary solution: I am disabling the MSSP peripheral, making the SDA line an input, and manually generating 9 clocks in SCL to make the slave release the SDA line, checking if the SDA has returned to zero.

Comment: 2) There is no problem with the data itself, I can write one or more bytes and when I make a sequential read I receive the data correctly, the slave just hold SDA low after that.

Comment: If manually unblocking the bus works, the PIC and the EEPROM lost synchronicity. Maybe you should wait after NotAckI2C() using IdleI2C()? You should probably double check that the data you receive is really the data in the EEPROM. If reads and writes are faulty, the effects might cancel each other out. Use an oscilloscope. SDA should return to 1, not 0. Your choice of addresses might indicate that you're exceeding the address space and the EEPROM enters undefined behavior. This might happen if your address logic is faulty, as some vendors might require the uppermost address bit to be always 0.

Comment: I am sure that there's no problem with the data or the adress, because after I unblock the bus I can make a new read and the data will check with the one I've written before. Just to show an example of what I'm doing: 1) I write a string("abcd") 2) wait for the write cycle to finish 3)read the string and check if it's the same that I wrote. In all cases it turns out to be the same 4) reset the bus 5)Repeat.  Maybe it is something related, but I can't think of a reason: I am writing and reading and the data always check. I will follow your suggestions and see if it solves the problem. Thanks.